# How to implement `loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin` in loopback 4?

Tags: loopbackjs

I found a problem when implementing it in loopback 4, because the structure of version 4 changed completely. there is no `model-config.json` file.
How do I add mixins property to server?

I want to add createdAt and updatedAt to each model on loopback 4

Answer (score 1):

you can write a BaseClass Model and then inherit it in your models.

`base-entity.model.ts`

```js
export abstract class BaseEntity extends Entity { 
  @property({
    type: 'date',
    default: () => new Date(),
    name: 'created_on',
  })
  createdOn?: Date;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    default: () => new Date(),
    name: 'modified_on',
  })
  modifiedOn?: Date;
}
```

`yourmodel.model.ts`

```js
export class Yourmodel extends BaseEntity {
  
}
```